# Rendering objects from array in React after Async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array `data` in my state, that contains a collection of objects, however when I try to access and render some of the information stored in the objects, none of the expected text appears on the page.

My current code for this is in my render function as follows:

```
<ul>
    {this.state.data.map(match =>
    <Link to={'teams/'+ team.homeId} key={match.id}><li>{match.homeTeam}</li></Link>
<ul>
```

When I check the elements in my console, I see `undefined` where I'm expecting my data.

The information is retrieved inside an `await axios.get()` request inside my `async componentDidMount()` function, which leads me to believe that the data may not be displaying correctly as it has not yet been retrieved when the render occurs, however I'm not sure.

I've previously tried to define `let match = this.state.data || {}` at the beginning of my render, so that my render would reload once the `setState` had taken place in my `componentDidMount`, however this did not work. Any directions would be appreciated.

EDIT as per MonteCristo request;

```
class Welcome extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        let res = await axios.get(`https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/livescores?api_token=${API}`)
        let matchInfo = new Array(res.data.data.length).fill().map(_ => ({}))

        res.data.data.forEach((id, i) => Object.assign(matchInfo[i], {id: id.id, homeScore: id.scores.localteam_score}, {awayScore: id.scores.visitorteam_score}))

        res.data.data.forEach((id, i) => {
            axios.get(`https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/teams/${id.localteam_id}?api_token=${API}`)
            .then(res1 => {
                Object.assign(matchInfo[i], {homeId: res1.data.data.id, homeTeam: res1.data.data.name})
            })
        })
        res.data.data.forEach((id, i) => {
            axios.get(`https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/teams/${id.visitorteam_id}?api_token=${API}`)
            .then(res2 => {
                Object.assign(matchInfo[i], {awayId: res2.data.data.id, awayTeam: res2.data.data.name})
            })
        })
        res.data.data.forEach((id, i) => {axios.get(`https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/leagues/${id.league_id}?api_token=${API}`)
            .then(res3 => {
                Object.assign(matchInfo[i], {leagueName: res3.data.data.name})
            })
        })
        this.setState({
            data: [...this.state.data, ...matchInfo]
        })
    }


    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <p className="text-xl font-semibold">Live Matches</p>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.data.map(match => 
                        <Link to={'teams/'+ match.homeId} key={match.id}><li>{match.homeTeam}</li></Link>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: are you getting an data as an array or object? `.map` works only with an array

Comment: @MonteCristo `this.state.data` is an array of objects.

Comment: can you update the question with entire component code?

Comment: @MonteCristo Sure, one moment.

Comment: @MonteCristo There you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually wait for the requests to complete.

You're doing a `this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...matchInfo] })` at the bottom, but you are mutating the `matchInfo` objects asynchronously, so `setState` is occurring *before* all those axios requests complete. Mutating state will not cause re-renders, only setting it via `setState`.

If you await all your axios calls instead and build your object before calling `setState`, you'll get what you are looking for:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const soccerApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0',
    params: { api_token: API }
  });
  const res = await soccerApi.get(`/livescores`);
  const matchInfo = await Promise.all(res.data.data.map(async row => {
    const [homeTeamInfo, awayTeamInfo, leagueInfo] = await Promise.all([
      soccerApi.get(`/teams/${row.localteam_id}`),
      soccerApi.get(`/teams/${row.visitorteam_id}`),
      soccerApi.get(`/leagues/${row.league_id}`)
    ]);
    return { 
      id: row.id,
      homeScore: row.scores.localteam_score,
      awayScore: row.scores.visitorteam_score,
      homeId: homeTeamInfo.data.data.id,
      homeTeam: homeTeamInfo.data.data.name,
      awayId: awayTeamInfo.data.data.id,
      awayTeam: awayTeamInfo.data.data.name,
      leagueName: leagueInfo.data.data.name
    };
  }));
  this.setState({
    data: [...this.state.data, ...matchInfo]
  });
}
```

Comment: I was able to verify that `this.state.data` was indeed populated by the info contained within `matchInfo`, by setting up a simple button in my page to console.log `this.state.data`  

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're explaining?

Comment: @Tigerr107: you may see the data in the console because your code is _mutating_ the object, but you're calling `setState` before the object is mutated. React will not detect if you mutate objects and know to re-render; that's why immutability is strongly encouraged. It's better to do a setState only once you actually have the data, or if you want to incrementally render as it changes, you'll need to call setState periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that data was retrieved successfully like this:

```
<ul>
{this.state.data && this.state.data.map(match => {
return (<Link to={'teams/'+ team.homeId} key={match.id}>{match.homeTeam}</Link>)
}
 <ul>
```

Comment: This is also failing to display any of the data, however when I console.log `this.state.data` using a button on my page, the array is full.

Comment: I think `}` missing too at the end. but not sure if its typo or not when copied from IDE to SO

Comment: After balancing as followed:  
`.map(match => {
return (<Link>...</Link>)})}`
It still outputs nothing onto the page, really not sure whats going wrong at this point, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is your axios calls in forEach. you're not waiting for them. you are calling them within the forEach instead of waiting.

so you'd need to do something like this

```
const allPromises = res.data.data.map((id, i) => { return axios.get() } 

// then 

const allResponseValues = await axios.all(allPromises).catch(console.error)

// do something with allResponses and update matchInfo

// finally
this.setState({...})
```

also update your render function to below for readability and clarity

```
            {this.state.data.map(match => (
              <Link to={"teams/" + match.homeId} key={match.id}>
                <li>{match.homeTeam}</li>
              </Link>
            ))}
```